# MongoDB error: Insert date into MongoDB in ISO format through JSON file

Tags: json, mongodb, isodate

I have tried to load date field into MongoDB via JSON file but I'm getting error as write erros:

> {BulkWriteError{index=0,code-52,message='The doller($) prefixed field
> '$date' in 'ExpirationDate.$date' is not a valid for storage.'

Tried below methods, none of them are worked:

```
"ExpirartionDate":{
  "$date":"2020-07-07"
}

"ExpirartionDate":ISODate("2020-0-07")

"ExpirartionDate":{ISODate("2020-0-07")}
```

Please advise correct format to insert date as ISO date in MongoDB via JSON file.

Comment: Month and day must be 2 digits each: `ExpirartionDate: ISODate("2020-07-07")`

Answer (score 1):

From the official [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#mongodb-bsontype-Date):

> For dates between years 1970 and 9999, inclusive:

`{"$date": {"$numberLong": "<millis>"}}`

`{"$date": "<ISO-8601 Date/Time Format>"}`

> For dates before year 1970 or after year 9999:

`{"$date": {"$numberLong": "<millis>"}}`

Where the values are as follows:

```
"<millis>"
   - A 64-bit signed integer as string. The value represents milliseconds relative to the epoch.

"<ISO-8601 Date/Time Format>"
   - A date in [ISO-8601 Internet Date/Time Format](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3339#section-5.6) as string.

   - The date/time has a maximum time precision of milliseconds:
      - Fractional seconds have exactly 3 decimal places if the fractional part is non-zero.
      - Otherwise, fractional seconds SHOULD be omitted if zero.
```

The 'time' portion of an ISO 8601 date is optional.
So your first attempt will work, I just confirmed this.

Your json should looks like this:

```json
[
  {
    "ExpirationDate": { "$date": "2020-07-07" }
  }
]
```

Comment: i could able to insert document into Mongo manually ,but when I try to load with Kafka data feed they are facing above issue for '$date'

Comment: I have tried date without $ symbol it was stored as string.  I just want to save date in date format and i have tried $date and ISODate , both are not worked. Is there any other ways to send the date filed ?

Comment: Your issue doesn't seem to be with the format and importing but rather with your pipeline? How are you importing the json exactly?

Comment: i will send json document to Kafka topic , kafka will load the json to MongoDB

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongo-db-connector-for-apache-kafka-1-3-available-now              As per the above link it seems we could not do anything in json document, i have to define output schema in kafka for the date filed as date before loading to Mongodb, how can i define output schema?    my understanding is right?